# How can i auto update a Kendo Grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid which I have bound a datasource in AngularJS. It has 10 rows.
In the MVC controller that is called I do some calculations and refetch the new datasource associated with that Grid and 5 of the lines no longer need to be on the grid. 
The issue is that the rows are deleted from my model and database but I need to close my screen and come back to the Kendo Grid to see the change. 
Is there a way I can make the grid update with that new data , so of like an Autorefresh ?

Thanks

Comment: You can *refresh* your grid by executing `grid.dataSource.read()`. It will request the same api endpoint. If the result has less rows, less rows will be displayed.

Comment: And I assume that I need to set the datasource for the grid as an observeablearray ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to. Try a normal dataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep all sorted. using grid.datasource.read()